# Generate comma seperated string list from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write a function in PHP, but being a novice I am finding it a bit difficult to do so. I have an array which looks like

```
[{"x":"12345","y":"john"},{"x":"12345","y":"stars"}]
```

The function which I am writing is

```
function getCSV($x)
{

    // Now I want to pass the $x which in the above array is 12345 and get "john,stars"  as output
}
```

Are there any methods available in PHP that can do this, or what would be the best approach to  get it?

Comment: How are the keys related? You have `x` and `y` in the first, `uid1` and `uid2` in the second. And is the data actually an array that you're shorthanding, or is what you posted a string that you need to work with?

Comment: this is json string : use `json_decode()`

Comment: that was a typo. I have edited my question now

Comment: Your array doesn't make sense for what you're trying to do. Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a json to me

```
[{"x":"12345","y":"john"},{"uid1":"12345","uid2":"stars"}]


function getCSV($x)
{
    $arr = json_decode($x);
    echo $arr[0]->y . ', ' . $arr[1]->uid2;
}
```

This looks horrible, but withouth further explanation is the only thing that works

EDIT - after your edit

```
function getCSV($x)
{
    $arr = json_decode($x);
    $y = array();
    foreach($arr as $obj){
        $y[] = $obj->y;
    }
    return implode(',', $y);
}
```

here is a working pad http://codepad.org/HzttdmjW

Comment: `$x` is not the array, it's the value of key 'x' (12345).

Comment: [{"x":"12345","y":"john"},{"x":"12345","y":"stars"}] that is the actual json

Comment: @Sandhurst  yes but the `$x` that you pass to getCSV is the JSON?

Comment: @Truth thatmight be, but where is the JSON then?

Comment: $x will be a string value for instance "12345", it will not be in JSON format

Comment: @Sandhurst but to echo something you have to pass the JSON to the function. How can you have `john, stars` as an output if you just pass `12345` to a function?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti the scenario is I have an array of strings and the function getCSV() will take this string as an input and will then try  to get all the matching 'Y' from the JSON. So the JSON will be there inside the function and it will output different csv for different $x passed.

Comment: @Sandhurst so you are passing a string like `getCSV('[{"x":"12345","y":"john"},{"uid1":"12345","uid2":"stars"}]');`? in that case my code should work. If the string is different, just show me the string

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I am passing a string like getCSV("12345") and the output I am trying to get is "john,stars"

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti the JSON string that I have is [{"x":"12345","y":"john"},{"x":"12345","y":"stars"}]

Comment: @Sandhurst  than my code works, just use return instead of echo so thata string is returned http://codepad.org/HzttdmjW

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I am not going to pass JSON to getCSV function. I will be passing getCSV("12345");

Comment: @Sandhurst you should pass the JSON, because the only wayto do this withouth passing the JSON implies using a global variable, which is a bad practice

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti This is what I came up with using your suggestion, is this something you would recommend. http://codepad.org/QOmecO0J

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10321/discussion-between-sandhurst-and-nicola-peluchetti)

Comment: @Sandhurst i'd do this like this because it's mor reusable, and it's less coupled to a particular string that you hardcode inside it http://codepad.org/Gsi0v0e0